# Java and Void return statement

Tags: java, android, return

I've developed an android application, I know that **return;** within a void return method would break out of the flow. But, the android application does not return instead it continues to execute the code next to this block

**eg:**

```
public static void displayImage(String img){

    if(img.contains("http")){
        loadImage(img);
        return;
    }
    Uri uri = Uri.parseUri(img); // even though it hit the return statement above, it continued to this block
    .....
}
```

Even though the **return;** is executed, it continues to call the methods that are next to this block. Is it my compilation problem? or is it the way Java in Android works when debugging? I'm stumped please help me understand.

**Update:** The method is a static method, just to be precise

**Detailed explanation**

I have dropbox support for my android application, as per the [chooser api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/android) I have implemeneted the following in my `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == DBX_CHOOSER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            DbxChooser.Result result = new DbxChooser.Result(data);
            ..
            ContentHelper.displayImage(result.getData().toString());
        } else {
            // Failed or was cancelled by the user
```

Now in my `ContentHelper.java`

```
public static void displayImage(String img){

        if(img.contains("http")){
            loadImage(img);
            return;
        }
        Uri uri = Uri.parseUri(img); // even though it hit the return statement above, it continued to this block
        .....
        //load some activity etc.,
    }
```

Because this displayImage is capable of loading images from SD card and any link that it is given it has if block and return statements. (I know I can put `if .. else` and create a work on it. But my question is why did it not break at `return;`)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the `if` condition evaluated to true?

Comment: If return is called, the method will cease to execute. There is no exception to this.

Comment: are you even sure that img contains http??? and btw java will 100% return it.

Comment: @Eran Yes, I placed debug points and it evaluated to true, went into the if block.

Comment: Then either the debugger is showing you different code than what is executing, or the method is being called again, when `img` does *not* contain `"http"`. If you're hitting that `return` statement, then the program will *not* continue to execute the following statements.

Comment: Have you used a log or anything to be sure that it runs that line? Depending on your IDE, execution may *appear* to continue when in fact the code isn't executed while debugging.

Comment: It's possible the code installed on your device is not the same as the code you see in eclipse. Try to clean, build and re-install the app.

Comment: I'll try cleaning and building again.

Comment: It seems to be a common issue with eclipse debugger.I've encountered the same ,it doesn't seem to be synchronous with the code execution.You could verify the same with a bunch of sysouts.

Comment: Include a `System.out.println()` right after the return, just to be sure.

Comment: This problem usually occurs (in my project) in life-cycle methods `onCreate(), onStop()` etc

Comment: @codehitman Your proposal will be thwarted by any decent compiler ("unreachable").

Comment: @laune true, but if he is claiming that execution moves past the return statement then that will prove conclusively if it is. Which it can't, but yeah....

Comment: @laune that aint true as long as the return is wrapped in a conditional block as is the case here

Comment: Updated the question as per the scenario I'm facing.

Comment: @root Please tell me whether "right after the return" implies to have a `}` between the `return` and the `println`? I'd expect "right after the block statement containing the return". English isn't my first language, so YMMV.

Comment: @laune: It seemed to me that his intent may have been to plug the sysout post the  braces. If not its as u said compiler rejection in which case my apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the environment of the code running is on the emulator or on an external device, it may be that there is inconsistancy between the code in eclipse where the debug information is shown and the actual running code in the external environment.

Cleaning, rebuilding and re-installing the app will definitely solve the issue.